# How to Convert to UTC

Tags: php, datetime, utc, gmt

I'm getting dates & times from various sources (e.g. file's date/time from FTP server, email's date/tiem received, etc.) and need to store them all as UTC (so they all have a common reference). How do I do this? What pieces of information do I need in order to properly do the conversion.

This is for a PHP web application. So, I can get my server's time zone. I'm not sure what to do next. Here are some sample inputs:

1. Mon, 28 Jun 2010 12:39:52 +1200
2. 2010-06-25 15:33:00

Comment: Are you storing them in MySQL? If so, you can use MySQL's date functions to do the conversions. PHP's date functions are quite limited unless you have at least version 5.3.0.

Comment: Yes, MySQL. I'm thinking that "Mon, 28 Jun 2010 12:39:52 +1200" will convert nicely as I have a "+1200" offset. However, "2010-06-25 15:33:00" seems useless.

Can you explain furthere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first case the offset is there so it should be trivial, the second example however will be considered as UTC (or any other default timezone). This is what I suggest:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); // set default timezone

$one = strtotime('Mon, 28 Jun 2010 12:39:52 +1200');
$two = strtotime('2010-06-25 15:33:00'); // Already UTC? Must be...
```

`$one` and `$two` will hold the timestamps of the correspondent time converted to the UTC timezone.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`strtotime()`](http://us.php.net/strtotime) to convert whatever time format you have into a timestamp and then use whatever function, probably `date()`, to put it in the format you want everything to be stored in.