# How to convert time string into UTC?

Tags: php, time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Convert to UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243081/how-to-convert-to-utc)

I'm parsing data from one API, and get following "published_time" data:
2011-11-23T10:00:30Z

I'm not sure how that format is called, but I need that converted into UTC date or at least, local time. How can I do that in PHP?

Thanks

Comment: Just use strtotime and store it as a timestamp

Comment: Thanks, didn't realized strtotime can parse that.

Answer (score 1):

That's [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) - and technically [it's already UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC).

It should be parseable using [`strtotime()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) (as long as you're running PHP 5.0+) if you want to be able to work with it as a UNIX timestamp.

Comment: "UTC timestamp"? I think you mean "UNIX timestamp".

Comment: Ah I remove my downvote since you've fixed it.

Comment: edited to UNIX, although that's generally considered a minor squabble (since Unix timestamps roughly approximately UTC time, minus leap seconds).